# Importing a snapshot version of a dependency into Maven repository

Tags: maven, grails, plugins, nexus, snapshot

I am having trouble importing dependencies for my Grails project into the company Nexus repository. The Grails plugin I would like to use is events-push (https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push). The latest released version of the plugin is 1.0.M7. It uses a very old version of Atmosphere library. The GutHub repository contains a more up-to-date version of events-push plugin, 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. I built the Grails plugin from the local clone of the repository and got it to work in my dev environment.

To deploy it on the intranet (in the production environment) I need to import all the plugin dependencies into the company Nexus repository. This is where I run into trouble. The project depends on a SNAPSHOT version of events-push plugin, which in turn depends on SNAPSHOT version of other Grails plugins and Java libraries (according to dependency report).

Nexus supports two types of repositories, Release and Snapshot. I can add artifacts to a Release repository (through the browser UI or in a batch mode using curl), but the artifact must not be a snapshot. I can change the repository to be a Snapshot repository, but then I lose the ability to add artifact to it through the browser or curl command.

How do I make these SNAPSHOT artifacts available to the Grails project through Maven?

Comment: Is the problem that you can't push the artifact into your nexus SNAPSHOTS repo, or that you can't get Maven/Grails to pull it down from that repo? If it's the latter, post your pom and .settings file...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change them to a release version and deploy them to the release repository.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly that. The crux of the matter was that the plugin was left in an unfinished state. The version on the GitHub was operational but was listed as snapshot and it depended on snapshot versions of other Grails plugins and libraries. I did have to change the dependencies to release versions, change the plugin version itself to a release version, rebuild the plugin and import the new dependencies into the company repo.